# Changing the color of the line series

Tags: html, css, d3.js

I am trying to create a D3 line chart. I have copied the code from the block builder and replaced with my data. Although the code is working but i am trying to change the color of the line series but unable to locate the code.

Could anyone help me in changing the color of the line (orange to red)

Original Block https://bl.ocks.org/larsenmtl/e3b8b7c2ca4787f77d78f58d41c3da91

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  body {
    font: 12px Helvetica;
  }

  .axis line {
    fill: red;
    stroke: #2b2b2b;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

  .x.axis path {
    display: none;
  }

  .line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 3px;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
  <script>
    var margin = {
        top: 50,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 80
      },
      width = 830 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
      .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .ticks(10)
      .innerTickSize(2)
      .outerTickSize(0)
      .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .tickFormat(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .ticks(10)
      .innerTickSize(2.5)
      .outerTickSize(0)
      .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("basis")
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.price);
      });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vaibhavjaitly/f1339c2bc02857afdf65b8d572dc31e5/raw/72ad1af2eacc86575649ae015b433aacb37f3854/US.and.SF.Crimerate.csv", function(error, data) {
      color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
        return key !== "Year";
      }));

      var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
        return {
          name: name,
          values: data.map(function(d) {
            return {
              date: d.Year,
              temperature: +d[name]
            };
          })
        };
      });

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.Year);
      });

      var companies = color.domain().map(function(name) {
        return {
          name: name,
          values: data.map(function(d) {
            return {
              date: d.date,
              price: +d[name]
            };
          })
        };
      });

      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return d.date;
      }));

      y.domain([
        d3.min(companies, function(c) {
          return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
            return v.price;
          });
        }),
        d3.max(companies, function(c) {
          return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
            return v.price;
          });
        })
      ]);

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

     // svg.append("g")
     //   .attr("class", "y axis")
   //     .call(yAxis)

      svg.append("line")
        .attr({
          "class": "horizontalGrid",
          "x1": 33,
          "x2": width,
          "y1": y(0),
          "y2": y(0),
          "fill": "none",
          "shape-rendering": "crispEdges",
          "stroke": "black",
          "stroke-width": "1px",
          "stroke-dasharray": ("3, 3")
        });


      var company = svg.selectAll(".company")
        .data(companies)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "company");

      var path = svg.selectAll(".company").append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          return line(d.values);
        })
        .style("stroke", function(d) {
          return color(d.name)
        });

      var totalLength = [path[0][0].getTotalLength(), path[0][1].getTotalLength()];

      d3.select(path[0][0])
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength[0] + " " + totalLength[0])
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength[0])
        .transition()
        .duration(8000)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

      d3.select(path[0][1])
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength[1] + " " + totalLength[1])
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength[1])
        .transition()
        .duration(8000)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

      var mouseG = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

      mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
        .attr("class", "mouse-line")
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("stroke-width", "1px")
        .style("opacity", "0");

      var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

      var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
        .data(cities)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

      mousePerLine.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 7)
        .style("stroke", function(d) {
          return color(d.Year);
        })
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke-width", "1px")
        .style("opacity", "0");

      mousePerLine.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(10,3)");

      mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
        .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
        .attr('height', height)
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
        .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
          d3.select(".mouse-line")
            .style("opacity", "0");
          d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
            .style("opacity", "0");
          d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
            .style("opacity", "0");
        })
        .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
          d3.select(".mouse-line")
            .style("opacity", "1");
          d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
            .style("opacity", "1");
          d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
            .style("opacity", "1");
        })
        .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
          var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
          d3.select(".mouse-line")
            .attr("d", function() {
              var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
              d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
              return d;
            });

          d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              var xYear = x.invert(mouse[0]),
                bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) {
                  return d.Year;
                }).right;
              idx = bisect(d.values, xYear);

              var beginning = 0,
                end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
                target = null;

              while (true) {
                target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
                pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
                if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                  break;
                }
                if (pos.x > mouse[0]) end = target;
                else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
                else break; //position found
              }

              d3.select(this).select('text')
                .text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

              return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
            });
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Is this all the code? I don't see the part for the `<path>` elements which are wrapped in `<g>` elements with the class of `city`. U need to change the `stroke` attribute of those `<path>` elements.

Comment: @Amiratak88 it's right there: `var path = svg.selectAll(".company").append("path")`.

Comment: I saw ***g*** elements with ***city*** class not ***company*** in my browser dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom colors to match your requirements.

In your code you have line

`var color = d3.scale.category10();`

so just replace that with your preferred colors (order is the order of the data).

`var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(['red', 'green', 'blue']);`

or

`var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff']);`